# About WordPress keep slug remembered

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies

There are 3 main slug options in this WordPress website. If you go to the main domain, you go to /. But when you go to the page /example, then it should redirect to this slug next time when you visit the main domain (www.example.com). This rule should apply for: /home, /example, /milk.

```
global $post;
$pages = ['home', 'example', 'milk'];

if(is_home() && isset($_COOKIE['page']) && in_array($_COOKIE['page'], $pages))
{
    header( get_permalink( get_page_by_path($_COOKIE['page']) ), true, 302);
    exit;
}

if(is_page($pages))
{
    setcookie('page', $post->slug, time()+3600*24*100, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it with [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) instead of header.

i'm assuming your redirect does not work at the moment because it needs to be header('location:$URL');

If this is not the issue then please explain what exactly does not work in your current code